# Differences in multimedia frameworks

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer, vlc, phonon, libvlc

I've been recently investigating different **multimedia frameworks** for adding audio and video capabilities to my applications.

I've been looking at **phonon, gstreamer, ffmpeg, libvlc/vlc**.

However, I cannot find a good resource that answers some of my general questions.

- Are these interchangeable?
- Do they work in the same level?
- Do you have any experience using some and can give feedback of why did you chose one over the other?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Are these interchangeable?

generally not. Phonon is a high level api that wraps actual multimedia frameworks, which allows you to change the backend, but on the other hand limits what you can do.

> Do they work in the same level?

no. some of the ones you mentioned are high level, some are low level.

> Do you have any experience using some and can give feedback of why did you chose one over the other?

You should really tell what you want to do. Then people can advise what framework might be suitable. Lower level frameworks such as gstreamer cover quite a large variety of use cases.

Comment: Thanks ensonic. Regarding your last answer, I want to create a simple multiplatform (linux, mac, win) audio and video player (mainly for getting used to some framework and then be able to use it in other applications).

Comment: @user1837038 See `ffplay` for an example of a simple player. It uses FFmpeg and SDL libraries, and is multiplatform.

Comment: All of the should be useable for this purpose. if you plan to use qt, phonon might sound like a good fit, but please remmeber it is an extra layer. gstreamer e.g. has qt bindings (qtgstreamer).

Answer (score 0):

There is a 'GStreamer SDK' for windows and OS/X which should get you started easily on those platforms (on Linux you can just install your distro's -dev packages). The SDK ships with snappy, which is a small media player using clutter, but you can easily build your own player using some other toolkit or API of course.